# How to get new stack/package installed into your Ubuntu?

Tags: ros, stack, package, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a new learner of ROS. On my project, I need a new stack which is not installed by default, so I have tried the command "rosdep" while it dose not work, here is some results:
wbin@wbin:~$ rosdep install pr2_cockpit

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource pr2_cockpit
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/wbin/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

Is any way to get new stacks/packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42444/how-to-get-new-stack/package-installed-into-your-ubuntu?/) by [lucifer wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3098/lucifer-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To install a stack from source, it is recommended to use the tool [rosws](http://ros.org/wiki/rosws).

First you need to create an overlay. Have a look at [this wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) for information on how to do that. Then you can easily check add stacks from source using roslocate in combination with `rosws merge` or `rosws --set` as shown on the above wiki page. Given your overlay is set up correctly, you can check out pr2_cockpit as follows:

```
roslocate info pr2_cockpit | rosws merge -
rosws update
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-08-27**:
Thanks for the information Lorenz. I have used this method as well but somehow I felt the method I suggested more convenient and simple. Sure, I would try to make it a habit to use this new method hereafter. :)

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-28**:
why need sandbox ?!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Installing new stacks available in ros.org is a very simple task which you can do using the svn command on the page of the sstack you are looking for.

You may search for the particluar stack that you require from the homepage of ros.org Here's the link of the stack you were looking for:

[pr2_cockpit](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_cockpit)

In the homepage of the stack they have provided the svn link for their stack. You can simply open a terminal and enter the following command:

> svn co /< link of the svn >

For your particular case it would be:

> svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_cockpit/trunk

You may sometimes require to be a super user so you may use 'sudo' if it did not work without the additional rights.

Remember after this process the entire stack will be downloaded into the current directory of the terminal. You may before hand change the directory of the terminal to the stacks directory of ros or any location that is in $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

You can also download the tool rapid_svn which is available in the software centre and is a comfortable gui for download of repositories and svn checkouts.

Hope that helps.

Good luck,

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) with karma: 612 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-27**:
It is not recommended to manually manage the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH but to use rosws. Also, only rosdep should require sudo, nothing else.

**Comment by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on 2013-03-29**:
I agree and also would like to add that using git command also works.